# Odoo 12: 'report.label.report_label' AttributeError

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I am using a third-party module in Odoo to do mass label printing (https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/12.0/label/) and despite the fact that the module claims to be compatible with version 12, I am getting server errors when trying to run the pdf rendering:

```
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1677, in report_download
response = self.report_routes(reportname, converter=converter, **dict(data))
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 517, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1614, in report_routes
pdf = report.with_context(context).render_qweb_pdf(docids, data=data)[0]
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py", line 677, in render_qweb_pdf
html = self.with_context(context).render_qweb_html(res_ids, data=data)[0]
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py", line 710, in render_qweb_html
data = self._get_rendering_context(docids, data)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py", line 723, in _get_rendering_context
data.update(report_model._get_report_values(docids, data=data))
AttributeError: 'report.label.report_label' object has no attribute '_get_report_values'
```

Screenshot:
[image]

It may be an error related to the change of some Odoo version (or not, I don’t really know).

Does anyone know if this attribute exist? I haven’t been able to find this information in the Odoo documentation (it doesn’t seem very complete regarding these topic).

Here are some screenshots of the configurations I’m using:

[image: Odoo]
[image: Odoo]
[image: Odoo]
[image: Odoo]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

From the traceback you shared on first screenshot, the problem seems to be with `report_model` variable which is reference to `report.label.report_label` object, defined in `label/report/dunamic_model.py` file which contains the method `get_report_values`. But from odoo 12 community code, `ir.actions.report` is looking for `_get_report_values`, the mismatch between this two method name is actually causing the problem.

Comment: Thank you for this workaround! The pdf generation is now working. Nevertheless, now the generated pdf is blank (empty page), with 0 bytes. Am I missing something? It could be that my configuration is wrong. Do you have any working example? Thank you so much.

Comment: I did worked with mass label printing but didn't got the chance to work on this particular module. Sure it can be debugged what causing the blank pdf generation.